# Spring boot JWT auth by user id

Tags: java, spring-boot, jwt

I am in trouble I want login by mail(username) and password but method getName on Principal object must return user Id not user mail. I am trying with userDetails but i don't have any correct result.

I've got two type of users: Specialist and Customer which implemented UserDetails interface.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "customer")
public class Customer implements UserDetails {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "uuid", strategy = "uuid2")
    @Column(name = "customer_id",updatable = false)
    private String customerId;
    @NotBlank(message = "Nickname may not be blank")
    @Size(min = 3, max = 20, message = "Nickname '${validatedValue}' isn't correct => must be between {min} and {max} characters")
    @Column(name = "nickname",updatable = false)
    private String nickname;
    @NotBlank(message = "City may not be blank")
    @Size(min = 3, max = 25, message = "City '${validatedValue}' isn't correct => must be between {min} and {max} characters")
    @Column(name = "city")
    private String city;
    @NotBlank(message = "Phone Number may not be blank")
    @Pattern(regexp="(^$|[0-9]{9})")
    @Column(name = "phone_number",updatable = false)
    private String phoneNumber;
    @NotBlank(message = "Email may not be blank")
    @Email
    @Column(name = "mail",updatable = false)
    private String mail;
    @Transient
    private String confirmMail;
    @NotBlank(message = "Password may not be blank")
    @Size(min = 5 , message = "Password '${validatedValue}' isn't correct => must be between {min} characters")
    @Column(name = "password")
    private String password;
    @Transient
    private String confirmPassword;
```

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "specialist")
public class Specialist implements UserDetails {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "uuid", strategy = "uuid2")
    @Column(name = "specialist_id",updatable = false)
    private String specialistId;
    @NotBlank(message = "Name may not be blank")
    @Size(min = 3, max = 20, message = "Name '${validatedValue}' isn't correct => must be between {min} and {max} characters")
    @Column(name = "name",updatable = false)
    private String name;
    @NotBlank(message = "Surname may not be blank")
    @Size(min = 3, max = 20, message = "Name '${validatedValue}' isn't correct => must be between {min} and {max} characters")
    @Column(name = "surname",updatable = false)
    private String surname;
    @NotNull(message = "Province may not be blank")
    @Column(name = "province")
    private Province province;
    @NotBlank(message = "City may not be blank")
    @Size(min = 3, max = 25, message = "City '${validatedValue}' isn't correct => must be between {min} and {max} characters")
    @Column(name = "city")
    private String city;
    @NotBlank(message = "Profession may not be blank")
    @Size(min = 3, max = 25, message = "Profession '${validatedValue}' isn't correct => must be between {min} and {max} characters")
    @Column(name = "profession")
    private String profession;
    @NotBlank(message = "Phone Number may not be blank")
    @Pattern(regexp="(^$|[0-9]{9})")
    @Column(name = "phone_number",updatable = false)
    private String phoneNumber;
    @NotBlank(message = "Email may not be blank")
    @Email
    @Column(name = "mail",updatable = false)
    private String mail;
    @Transient
    private String confirmMail;
    @NotBlank(message = "Password may not be blank")
    @Size(min = 5 , message = "Password '${validatedValue}' isn't correct => must be between {min} characters")
    @Column(name = "password")
    private String password;
    @Transient
    private String confirmPassword;
    private Integer numberOfRatings = 0;
    @Range(min = 0 , max = 5)
    @Column(name = "average_rate")
    private Double averageRate = 0.0;
    private Double sumOfRatingsValue = 0.0;
```

Token Provider:

```
@Component
public class JwtTokenProvider {
//Start POINT
public String generateTokenForSpecialist(Authentication authentication){
    Specialist specialist = (Specialist) authentication.getPrincipal();
    Date now = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis());
    Date expiryDate = new Date(now.getTime() + EXPIRATION_TIME);
    String userId = specialist.getSpecialistId();
    Map<String,Object> claims = new HashMap<>();
    claims.put("id",specialist.getSpecialistId());
    claims.put("mail", specialist.getMail());


    return Jwts.builder()
            .setSubject(userId)
            .setClaims(claims)
            .setIssuedAt(now)
            .setExpiration(expiryDate)
            .signWith(SignatureAlgorithm.HS512, SECRET)
            .compact();

}

    public String generateTokenForCustomer(Authentication authentication){
        Customer customer = (Customer)authentication.getPrincipal();
        Date now = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis());
        Date expiryDate = new Date(now.getTime() + EXPIRATION_TIME);
        String userId = customer.getCustomerId();
        Map<String,Object> claims = new HashMap<>();
        claims.put("id",customer.getCustomerId());
        claims.put("mail", customer.getMail());


        return Jwts.builder()
                .setSubject(userId)
                .setClaims(claims)
                .setIssuedAt(now)
                .setExpiration(expiryDate)
                .signWith(SignatureAlgorithm.HS512, SECRET)
                .compact();

    }


    boolean validateToken(String token) {
        try{
            Jwts.parser().setSigningKey(SECRET).parseClaimsJws(token);
            return true;
        }catch (SignatureException ex){
            System.out.println("Invalid JWT Signature");
        }catch (MalformedJwtException ex){
            System.out.println("Invalid JWT Token");
        }catch (ExpiredJwtException ex){
            System.out.println("Expired JWT token");
        }catch (UnsupportedJwtException ex){
            System.out.println("Unsupported JWT token");
        }catch (IllegalArgumentException ex){
            System.out.println("JWT claims string is empty");
        }
        return false;
    }

    String getUserIdFromJWT(String token){
        Claims claims = Jwts.parser().setSigningKey(SECRET).parseClaimsJws(token).getBody();
        return (String)claims.get("id");
    }

}
```

Filter:

```
public class JwtAuthenticationFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    @Autowired
    private JwtTokenProvider tokenProvider;

    @Autowired
    private CustomUserDetailsService customUserDetailsService;

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse, FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {

        try{

            String jwt = getJWTFromRequest(httpServletRequest);
            if(StringUtils.hasText(jwt) && tokenProvider.validateToken(jwt)){
                String userId = tokenProvider.getUserIdFromJWT(jwt);
                UserDetails user = customUserDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(userId);

                UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authentication = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                        user,null, user.getAuthorities()
                );

                authentication.setDetails(new WebAuthenticationDetailsSource().buildDetails(httpServletRequest));
                SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
            }

        }catch (Exception ex){
            logger.error("Could not set user authentication in security context", ex);
        }

        filterChain.doFilter(httpServletRequest,httpServletResponse);
    }

    private String getJWTFromRequest(HttpServletRequest request) {

        String bearerToken = request.getHeader(HEADER_STRING);

        if(StringUtils.hasText(bearerToken) && bearerToken.startsWith(TOKEN_PREFIX)){
            return bearerToken.substring(7, bearerToken.length()-1);
        }
        return null;

    }
}
```

```
@Service
public class CustomUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {

    private final SpecialistRepo specialistRepo;

    private final CustomerRepo customerRepo;

    @Autowired
    public CustomUserDetailsService(SpecialistRepo specialistRepo, CustomerRepo customerRepo) {
        this.specialistRepo = specialistRepo;
        this.customerRepo = customerRepo;
    }

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        if(specialistRepo.findByMail(username) != null){
            return specialistRepo.findByMail(username);
        }else if(customerRepo.findByMail(username) != null){
            return customerRepo.findByMail(username);
        }else throw new UsernameNotFoundException("User not found");
    }

    @Transactional
    public UserDetails loadUserById(String id){
        if(specialistRepo.findBySpecialistId(id) != null){
            return specialistRepo.findBySpecialistId(id);
        }else if(customerRepo.findByCustomerId(id) != null){
            return customerRepo.findByCustomerId(id);
        }else throw new  UsernameNotFoundException("User not found");
    }
}
```

and login method in service:

```
  @Override
    public String login(LoginRequest loginRequest){
        Authentication authentication = authenticationManager.authenticate(
                new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                        loginRequest.getMail(),
                        loginRequest.getPassword()
                )
        );
        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
        String jwtToken;
        if(customerRepo.findByMail(loginRequest.getMail()) == null){
            if(specialistRepo.findByMail(loginRequest.getMail()).isEnabled()) jwtToken = TOKEN_PREFIX + tokenProvider.generateTokenForSpecialist(authentication);
            else throw new UnconfirmedAccountException("Specialist Please confirm you account by token from mail");
        }else {
            if(customerRepo.findByMail(loginRequest.getMail()).isEnabled()) jwtToken = TOKEN_PREFIX + tokenProvider.generateTokenForCustomer(authentication);
            else throw new UnconfirmedAccountException("Customer Please confirm you account by token from mail");
        }
        return jwtToken;
    }
```

When I login successfully then i want for example to add commission from other service but in this way this work only if I find user by mail but i want find user by userId.

There is a example:

```
 @PostMapping("/add")
    public ResponseEntity<?> addCommission(@Valid @RequestBody Commission commission, Principal principal){


        Commission newCommission = commissionServiceImpl.createCommission(commission,principal.getName());
        return new ResponseEntity<>(newCommission,HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }
```

and service:

```
  @Override
    public Commission createCommission(Commission commission,String customerId) {
        try{
        Customer customer = customerRepo.findByCustomerId(customerId);
            commission.setCustomer(customer);

        return commissionRepo.save(commission);
        }catch (Exception e){
            throw new CommissionIdException("Commission with ID '" + commission.getCommissionId() + "' already exist";
        }
    }
```

Maybe anyone have got any idea to solve this because i must get Id by principal.getName. Otherwise I must rebuild all of my application.

Comment: @Domimic Did you get answer for this? I  am also facing the same issue.